# Element within iframe, centered within parent window/viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

##### Context

I have a weird situation where there's a long iframe displayed on the page, and the viewport only sees a particular section of it at any one time. Apologies for the terrible picture, but it looks something like this:

[image: viewport over the top of a large iframe]

##### Question

I control the content of the iframe, but *not* the parent window. I'd like to center a modal within the viewport (i.e. parent window) when the user clicks a button within the iframe. You can assume the viewport is always *within* the bounds of the iframe - i.e. the iframe covers the full parent page.

##### Current solution

Here's a very hacky solution here involving 'polling' an intersection observer on an element (within the iframe) that covers the full iframe page:

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<div style="pointer-events:none;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;opacity:0.4;background: blue;z-index: 3;"></div>`;
let trackerEl = div.firstElementChild;
document.body.append(trackerEl);

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if(entry.isIntersecting) {
    const { x, y, width, height } = entry.intersectionRect;
    console.log(`Overlap bounds: x=${x}, y=${y}, width=${width}, height=${height}`);
    observer.unobserve(trackerEl);
    setTimeout(() => observer.observe(trackerEl), 100); // retrigger intersection
  }
});

observer.observe(trackerEl);
```

This isn't a full working example - it's just to illustrate. I'd only need to run that polling when the modal is visible.

Another way that kinda works is using the user's click location to "guess" where the modal should go, but that's not great either, since the modal would be fixed in a particular position.

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way (ideally just involving CSS, of course) that I'm naively overlooking here?

Comment: I don't see _any_ chance of a pure CSS solution here - CSS has no idea where your iframe currently is, in relation to the parent page.

Comment: _"I'd like to center a modal within the viewport (i.e. parent window) when the user clicks a button within the iframe."_ - I would imagine that depending on where your button is located, there might also be situations where that won't even be possible, without scrolling the parent document first ...? Like, say, the button was at the very bottom, and I scrolled the parent page so far that only a tiny bottom fraction of the iframe was still visible - then you likely won't be able to center your modal, which is part of the iframe, in regard to the parent to begin with.